# Copy assignment operator with non-copyable members

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

Say I have a class `A` with only a constructor:

```
struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
};
```

I also have a class `B` which contains an instance of `A` and defines the copy constructor as follows:

```
struct B
{
    B() = default;
    B(const B& other) : _a{} {}
    A _a;
};
```

The constructor of `B` here simply initializes `_a` with a new instance of `A`. But, how could I write the assignment operator for `B` (since I can't "reinitialize" `_a`)?

Comment: What _should_ happen? Is it possible to give `A` something like a `reset` method that would be the equivalent of calling `operator=(A{})` if the assignment operator existed?

Comment: You have a few options: (1) Ignore `_a` leaving it alone when `B` is copied.  (2) Make `B` non-copyable.  (3) Hold the embedded `A` instance indirectly, e.g. `unique_ptr<A>` instead of `A`, so it can be remade.

Comment: You could try calling `_a.~A()` and using placement `new` to replace `_a` (`new (&_a) A`) . But this solution has subtle problems, specially the `A` constructor isn't `noexcept`. And since `A` seems to not be movable, it likely represents an unusual resource and isn't trivial. I'd consider having a `std::unique_ptr<A> _a;` instead of using `A` directly.

Comment: Maybe I could make A "moveable" and use the swap idiom for the assignment operator of B (since the copy constructor of B exists)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `operator=` to create a fresh new `A` similar to the copy constructor and if dynamic allocation is feasible you can use a `std::unique_ptr<A>` as member:

```
struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
};

struct B
{
    B() : _a{std::make_unique<A>()} {}
    B(const B& other) : _a{std::make_unique<A>()} {}
    B& operator=(const B& other) {
        _a = std::make_unique<A>();
        return *this;
    }
    std::unique_ptr<A> _a;
};
```

Though, if `B` has a non-copyable (non-movable) member, then the least surprise would be if `B` is also non-copyable (non-moveable).

Comment: operator= you mean?

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of class `A`, an instance of `A` is non-copyable and also non-moveable. Therefore, I accepted the answer of @463035818_is_not_a_number.

Here is another answer which assumes that `A` can be made moveable, just for completeness or in case it may be useful to somebody.

```
struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;
};

struct B
{
    B() = default;
    B(const B&) : _a{} {}
    B& operator=(B other)
    {
        std::swap(_a, other._a);
        return *this;
    }
    A _a;
};
```